# Hide <p:column> using CSS

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, visibility

I am using primefaces' DataTable, in which specific columns should not be displayed. I know there is the `rendered` attribute but this simply doesn't load the column in the DOM. I need the column to be loaded on the page, but hidden from the user's view.
I also tried using styling associated with the column's id :

```
<style>
    #hidden {
      visibility: hidden;
    } 
</style>

<p:dataTable>
   <p:column id="hidden">
     ...
   </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

Though it works with mere html tags, it doesn't here with PrimeFaces' `column`.
How can I do that I cannot see more solutions.

---

EDIT 1

I put the `style` attribute in the column tag:

```
<p:column  headerText="COLUMN" rendered="true" style="visibility: hidden;">
```

All the column's content has been removed, but the black line from rows and columns is still displayed. So there is a useless white column between the others. Almost there...

Comment: FYI, PrimeFaces provides support to do this client side using p:columnToggler: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/columnToggler.xhtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always use **"styleClass"** attribute to apply style in jsf.

```
<p:column  headerText="COLUMN" rendered="true" styleClass="hidden">
```

apply style as below :

```
.hidden{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Bhavin this completely solved the issue! The column IS hidden form the view but remains present in the DOM. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the padding and width to zero, but thick border-line can be seen between hidden column.

```
<p:column style="padding:0;width:0px;">
...
</p:column>
```

Comment: Thank you I tried, but the desired column wouldn't shrink  past its content's dimensions. In other words, it does shrink as long as the content remains visible. So this is not the expected result.